# sending IMAP commands using php

Tags: php, email, imap, yahoo-mail

I'm trying to access yahoo mail IMAP server with a php script. I read that yahoo requires a specific IMAP command “ID ("GUID" "1")”. How do I send this command ?

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, I don't believe you can access Yahoo's IMAP services externally. However, in general, you will want to use socket functions.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php

Answer (score 1):

This library was released a couple of days ago and says it supports Yahoo!'s IMAP variant: http://github.com/petewarden/handmadeimap (I've not tried it myself)